# How closely do the input buffer op-amps need to be matched on discrete instrumentation amplifiers?

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

For discrete three op-amp instrumentation amplifiers, we know it is very important that the resistors be matched.

[image]
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier

However, I have found almost nothing talking about matching of the input opamps. How important is it to match these opamps?

For example, do they need to be on the same die in the same package? Would using op-amps of the same type but in two separate packages destroy the common mode rejection? Or would the closed-loop gains sufficiently work itself out negative feedback reigned in the extremely high open-loop gain, even if the open-loop gains were different to begin with?

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking about this common circuit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instrumentation_amplifier (if so, please include such a schematic) Having two opamps on the same die doesn't necessarily mean that these opamps will have the same input DC offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At DC it doesn't much matter.

For good AC common-mode rejection you would be best to use two amplifiers on the same die at the inputs, otherwise you'll likely have a region where CMRR deteriorates. If you low pass filter the inputs such that those frequencies never make it to the inputs it may not matter much.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuec9w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you do an AC simulation of the above, and there is a mismatch of 16MHz to 15MHz GBW in OA1 vs. OA2, the CMRR is more like -20dB than -60dB, which is pretty material.

Answer (score 1):

You probably wouldn't want to use two different types of op-amps, or op-amps with wide variation in input offset current and voltage, but the open-loop gain and negative feedback will pretty much take care of any mismatch in the op-amps' process parameters.  They don't have to be on the same die.

The error due to resistor mismatch will be orders of magnitude greater than any error from finite open-loop gain in the amplifiers. (At least up until higher frequencies when the open-loop gain starts to roll off.)

Comment: Yes, of course not two different types. I was trying to say the same type of opamp, but one that comes in one per package so you need two different packages.

Comment: @DKNguyen Right- I've done it with single op-amps several times in the past and it's fine.